# what is meant by minimum element ? what's the difference between minimum and minimal element?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-cone

We say that $x ∈ S$ is the minimum element of $S$ (with respect to the generalized inequality $≼_K$) if, for every $y ∈ S$, we have $x ≼_K y$.

We say that $x ∈ S$ is a minimal element of $S$ (with respect to the generalized inequality $≼_K$) if, for every $y ∈ S, y ≼K x$ we have $y = x$.

We can describe minimum and minimal elements using simple set notation. A point $x ∈ S$ is the minimum element of S if and only if
$S ⊆ x + K$.
Here $x + K$ denotes all the points that are comparable to $x$ and greater than or
equal to $x$ (according to $≼_K$ ). A point $x ∈ S$ is a minimal element if and only if $(x − K) ∩ S = {x}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your definitions are incorrect.

> Something is *minimal* if nothing is smaller. Formally we write this
>   as "$y$ is minimal if $\forall x, y\leq_K x$."
>
> Something is *the minimum* if it is the unique minimal element.
>   Formally we write this as "$y$ is the minimum if $\forall x(x\leq_K
>  y\Rightarrow x=y)$. Alternatively, we can write "$y$ is minimum if $\forall x(x=y\lor y<_K x)$," where $a<_Kb\iff a\leq_Kb\land a\neq_Kb$.  Notice that the equality in both cases is actual equality, not equality in the partial ordering induced by $K$

Let's look at an example. Consider $\mathbb{C}$ equipped with the partial order induced by $|\cdot|$. The *minimal points* of $\{z:3\leq |z|\leq 5\}$ are the set $\{z:|z|=3\}$, but the function $f(z)=|z|$ has a *minimum value* of $3$ on that set. When talking about the output of the function, there is a unique smallest output, and so it's the minimum. When talking about the input there are multiple points that give rise to the smallest output, so those are minimal points.

A minimum point is always minimal, but the converse statement is not true in general. However, it is true for total orders.

Comment: i took that definition from boyd convex optimization book :\

Comment: 2.4.2 minimum and minimal elements page no 45 :\

Comment: @MORAMREDDYRAKESHREDDY double check that you copied the labels correctly. There are a couple of different ways to formalize these ideas, and looking at it again the idea is right but they're backwards. The first is minimal and the second is minimum, though awkwardly worded in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost correctly quoted the formal definitions (see @StellaBiderman 's answer), so I assume you're asking for the idea, expressed more in words.

"Minimum" means "smallest". In the usual ordering of the natural numbers $\{1, 2, \ldots \}$, the number $1$ is the minimum.

"Minimal" means "nothing is smaller". If you order the natural numbers starting with $2$ by divisibility, so $a "\le" b$ when $a$ divides $b$ then the minimal numbers are the prime numbers. $7$ isn't minimum - it's not smaller than everything else - but it is minimal - nothing is smaller than it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you copy the wrong labels or having incorrect definition, at least I didn't find this to be an errata of the book.

In Section 2.4.2 of Boyd (Convex Optimization), the difference is detailed, minimum if exists, must be unique; however, several minimals may be found for $S$ given an generalized inequality $\le_K$ induced by a proper cone $K$.

To see why *minimum* is defined in this way, let $x, y \in S$ and each is a minimum.
It follows that $x \ge_K y$ and $y \ge_K x$.
But $x-y\in K$  and $y-x\in K$ implies that $d\in K$ and $-d \in K$.
Assuming that $d \ne 0$, $td+t'(-d) = (t-t')d \in K$ for any nonnegative scalars $t, t'$.
So, $K$ contains the line defined by $0$ and $d$ which is impossible because $K$ must be proper.
Thus, *minimum* must be unique where $d=0 \implies x=y$.

Intuitively, for any $y \in S$, $y$ must be comparable with $x$. Hence, the *minimum* can be found because $x$ is smaller than or equal to all $y$.

To see the difference between *minimum* and *minimal*, for any $y \in S$ and $y \le_K x$ where $x$ is a *minimal* of $S$ with respect to $\le_K$, $y=x$.
However, $S$ may have several minimals because there may exist an $x' \in S$ which is not comparable with $x$.
If $\le_K$ is fortunately a total/linear order on $S$, you can talk about the *minimum*.
Otherwise, you can only talk about *minimals*. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)
Figure 2.17 in the book clearly illustrates these concepts.